# Spring Cloud Kafka Streams auto topic creation setting does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I try to disable automatic topic creation and it does not work. Java app (kafka-streams binder) always creates the topic.
My config:
Broker:

```
auto.create.topics.enable = false
```

and in application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.consumer-properties.allow.auto.create.topics=false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoCreateTopics=false
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.autoAddPartitions=false
```

it does not create topic "exampleOutput" but still creates a topic "exampleInput" when defined in this way:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-out-0.destination=exampleOutput
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0.destination=exampleInput
```

Versions are:

- spring-boot-starter-parent - 2.5.4
- spring-cloud.version - 2020.0.3

The whole project reproducing the issue is:
https://github.com/zurada/kafka-streams-demo-config

Please help
[Kafka Stream always triggers topic creation using Admin tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMCNP.png)

Comment: You should tag this with spring-cloud-stream. Did you find a solution?